# What are the conditions in which the following is a true statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

AmodY = X1

BmodY = X2

(X1+X2)modY = X3 = CmodY.

Where C = A+B, and Y is a set $\mathbb{R}$eal number

I was working my way through an exam, and had to prove a simple 2 evens or 2 odds added together equal an even, and this was the completely off the wall over-engineered solution I came up with, opposed to using the "boring" x=2a y=2b way, which I know to be true within the context of the exam question. However I suck at proofs, and am unsure if my off the wall way of solving the problem is actually true, it works in this case and I haven't been able to find a case where it is disproven, but I don't know how to prove (or disprove) a statement like this, so I can use it over the x=2a y=2b way.

Comment: It helps when $Y$ is positive or at least non-zero, and some people would treat  $\bmod$ as an equivalence rather than as a function, but you can say that if $A \equiv X_1 \pmod Y$ and $B \equiv X_2 \pmod Y$ then $A+B \equiv X_1+X_2 \pmod Y$ is always true since if $A=X_1+nY$ and  $B=X_2+mY$ for integers $n$ and $m$ then $A+B=X_1+X_2+(n+m)Y$

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.